# Output each child with a wrapper from React.Children array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this reusable component.

```
export const ListItems = ({ controls, children }) => {

const content = controls ? <PrivateComponent>{ children }</PrivateComponent> : children;

return <ul>{ content }</ul>

}
```

Seems pretty-straight forward. The idea is that, in PrivateComponent, I wanna wrap each of the children with an extra wrapper, something like this:

```
export const PrivateComponent = ({ children }) => {

const _children = React.Children.toArray(children);

return (

<div>{ _children.map(child => <SomeWrapper>{ child }</SomeWrapper> ) }</div>

);

}
```

My question is, is it correct to render child this way, or should I use cloneElement? Also, what should I use for the key of SomeWrapper in the map function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it correct to render child this way, or should I use cloneElement?

You can use the child instance directly, there is no problem there. You need `cloneElement` only if you want to change / add any props or swap out its own children, or if you need a duplicate because you intend to insert "the same child" in two different location in your DOM.

> what should I use for the key of SomeWrapper in the map function?

You can use `React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])` ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap)) which will automatically add keys.